# Modify values in dictionary, adding amount

Tags: python, dictionary

Code

```
dict = {}
flag = True
while True:  
    length = raw_input('enter length')
    amount = raw_input('enter amount')
    if (length == 'quit') or (amount == 'quit'):
        flag = False
        continue
```

I want to add code so

```
if key in dict:
     # previous value + amount
     # insert the new value to the key
else: 
     dict[length] = amount
```

for example:
my inputs are: `13000,2`
than: `12000: 2`
and again: `13000: 2`

so dict will include `13000: 4` and `12000: 2`

Comment: `if length in dict`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if length in dict:
    dict[length] += amount
else:
    dict[length] = amount
```

will add the new `amount` to dict entry for `length` if it exists and sets it to `amount` if it doesn't exist yet.